# set the local certificate for php built in web server

Tags: php, ssl, localhost

I serve (to test the api with PostMan) my api with the following command

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public
```

I've got the following error:

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I know that there are other posts about this issue. I already added the cacert.pem file to the php folders in Wamp and remove the # in the httpd.conf file (LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so).

Comment: php offloads ssl handling to the webserver as its not a webserver, so php -S wont work

Comment: `httpd.conf` and `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` don't have anything to do with PHP. They're part of the Apache web server. What server software do you want to use?

Comment: I have the same issue, but only on Windows. Do not have it on Ubuntu. Obviously added cacert.pem, etc